# Weird pointer function

Tags: c, function, pointers

```
void r(char *str) 
{
    char *new = str;
    while (*str != '\0') {
        if (*str != ' ') *(new++) = *str;
        str++;
    }
    *new = '\0';
}
```

I have this function but i don't understand the code after the if statement .I would be grateful if somebody could explain it to me.

Comment: Is that variable really named `new`?

Comment: Yep ...from the if statement i can see that it obviously does something with the space but cannot continue.

Comment: @Paulpro: Why not name it `new`? :) Guess what `sizeof('\0')` is!

Comment: @user2154323: It sounds like you could benefit from reading up on C. There are plenty of good books!

Comment: You can use a debugger to step through code, that's a great way to understand how things work.

Comment: @VladLazarenko Because new is a reserved word in `C++`, so it gets highlighted blue on StackOverflow by default. I think `sizeof('\0')` would be 1 since `'\0'` is a char.

Comment: @Paulpro: The type of character literal is `int`, so `sizeof('\0') == sizeof(int)`. This is C, not C++... And the fact that Stack Overflow cannot determine the language correctly is... well, not the language's problem :)

Comment: @VladLazarenko It's actually Google's prettify highlighter that has the problem of not knowing the difference.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This function is stripping spaces out of the passed in value `str`.

`*(new++) = *str;` means take the pointer to the string new and dereference it so that we can use it to store where in memeory it points.  Then take the value that is pointed to by str and dereference it to the char it points at.  Assign that char to where new is and then move the new pointer along to the next spot.  Finally, always move the str pointer along  with `str++` if ithe value is a space or not.

May be it would be clearer to you if were wrote this way:

```
void r(char *str) 
{
    char *new = str;
    int newStringIndex = 0;

    for(int i=0; str[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
         if (str[i] != ' ') 
         {
             new[newStringIndex++] = str[i];
         }
    }

    new[newStringIndex] = '\0';
}
```

Same code functionality, but using a for loop and array indexing instead of pointer math.

Comment: Thanks a lot my basic problem was exactly in the statement after "if".Now combined with the answer above everything is completely clear :)

Answer (score 4):

the function is removing spaces (in-place) - it copies everything but spaces to the same string as before.

so the if statement is saying: "if the character in str is not a space, then copy it to new" (which is in the same memory area as str, but will start to trail behind when str meets a space).

note how str is always incremented, but new is only incremented when a character is copied.  so str scans the whole string, but the data are copied to earlier in the string because new doesn't update when there's a space.

then finally a terminating null is added at new so that the shortened version terminates correctly.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the step-to step explanation :)

Answer (score 1):

This version of the program (K&R style!)  is shorter and does the same:

```
void r(char *str) 
{
    char *new;
    for (new=str; *new = *str++; ) {
        if (*new != ' ') new++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while (*str != '\0') {
    if (*str != ' ') *(new++) = *str;
    str++;
}
```

is equivalent to:

```
while (*str != '\0') {
    if (*str != ' ') {
        *new = *str;
        new++;
    }
    str++;
}
```